# Using GAE to commuicate with hardware web devices

Tags: google-app-engine

## GAE with Phython has Sandbox  restrictions

## Background

I am developing a watering system that will have WiFi front end to connect to our home router.  I am able to do port forwarding if nessecary on the router if nessecary.

My WiFi module has a TCP/IP stack on it an I am able to  do the following TCP/IP actions at the bottm below.

## Question

Can I use these TCP/IP functions on my WiFi module to communicate with GAE  as I think onlt GET and POST are allowed.  No TCP or UDP sockets.

Thanks in advance

Joe

## WiFi module available commands

## ARP, ICMP ping, FTP client, TELNET, HTTP, UDP, and TCP sockets

## WiFI module HTML CLIENT FEATURE

The module has a built-in HTML client. When enabled, the module can get or post data 
to a web server. For example, you can use the HTML client to post serial and/or sensor 
data to the host web server. This feature makes possible to provide Wi-Fi capabilities 
to applications such as GPS units, remote sensors, weather stations, etc.

4.4.1 Retrieve Web Server Data
In this example, you want to retrieve data from the web server with the format:
http://www.webserver.com/ob.php?obvar=WEATHER
To perform this function, use the following settings:
set ip proto 18 // Enable the HTML client
set dns name www.webserver.com// Set the web server name
set ip address 0// Turn on DNS
set ip remote 80// Set the web server port, 80 is standard
set com remote 0// Turn off the REMOTE string so that it

// does not interfere with the post 
To make the connection, use the opencommand or you can use open www.web-server.com 80. The user’s microprocessor writes the following string to the UART:

GET /ob.php?obvar=WEATHER \n\n

Where the\n is the linefeed character (decimal 10or hex 0xa). Two linefeeds are

## required for the web server toknow the page is complete.

Comment: At the moment, appengine can accept and make http requests (POST, GET, PUT etc). In addition you have access to xmpp.  sockets are coming.

Comment: @Tim - sockets are outbound only. Not useable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Well it says your HW module can do HTTP. So if this is true then yes, your HW module can send data (commands) to GAE.